# how to find the real path of folder with regular expression

Tags: linux, shell-script, regular-expression, directory

presto is distributed SQL query engine ,

and when we installed the presto then it should be created the following home folder

```
/application/DB/presto/presto-server-0.216
```

so we can say that

in order to capture the home presto we can do ( **its part of my bash script** )

```
PRESTO_HOME=` find  /application/DB/presto/ -maxdepth 1 | grep  presto-server `
echo $PRESTO_HOME
/application/DB/presto//presto-server-0.216
```

BUT ... since some users can rename the folder under **/application/DB/presto/** in order to install new version

then under **/application/DB/presto** , we can get the following folders:

```
/application/DB/presto/presto-server-HOLD_0.211
/application/DB/presto/_presto-server-0.212
/application/DB/presto/backup_presto-server-0.216.new
/application/DB/presto/presto-server-0.210.old
/application/DB/presto/presto-server-0.212.orig
```

so regarding that

what is the   right syntax in order to find the real path
as

```
/application/DB/presto/presto-server-0.216
```

notes:

**presto folder structure is always with**

presto-server-[ any float number or integer number ]

**VALID examples:**

```
/application/DB/presto/presto-server-0.736
/application/DB/presto/presto-server-0.936
/application/DB/presto/presto-server-1
/application/DB/presto/presto-server-1.9
/application/DB/presto/presto-server-12
```

**NON VALID examples**:

```
/application/DB/presto/presto-server-0.736-43.previos
/application/DB/presto/presto-server-0.936_old
/application/DB/presto/orig_presto-server-1
/application/DB/presto/presto-server-1.9.bck
/application/DB/presto/presto-server-PREVIOS
/application/DB/presto/presto-server-
/application/DB/presto/presto-server-0.936_old
/application/DB/presto/orig_presto-server-1.other
/application/DB/presto/presto_server-1.9.bck
/application/DB/presto/OLD_presto-server-12-83
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on which shell you're using, you could do it with globbing.

### bash

```
#! /bin/bash -
shopt -s nullglob extglob
dirs=(/application/DB/presto/presto-server-+([[:digit:]])*(.+([[:digit:]])))

printf '%s\n' "Found ${#dirs[@]} matching directories:" "${dirs[@]}"
```

### zsh

```
#! /bin/zsh -
set -o extendedglob
dirs=(/application/DB/presto/presto-server-<->(.<->)#(N))

printf '%s\n' "Found $#dirs matching directories:" $dirs
```

### ksh93

```
#! /bin/ksh93 -
dirs=(~(N)/application/DB/presto/presto-server-+([[:digit:]])*(.+([[:digit:]])))

printf '%s\n' "Found ${#dirs[@]} matching directories:" "${dirs[@]}"
```

For all, that's `presto-server-` followed by a sequence of 1 or more digits followed by 0 or more sequences of `.<digits>`.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU find's `-regex` test, you could use:

```
find /application/DB/presto/ -regex '/application/DB/presto/presto-server-\([0-9]*\.\)?[0-9]+'
```

... which requires the leading path, and then the numeric part:

- optionally: leading digits and a period
- one or more digits

That matches all and only your "valid" examples, and none of your "invalid" examples.

Change the `[0-9]*` to `[0-9]+` if you want to require a digit before any leading period; the difference between:

> /application/DB/presto/presto-server-0.936

and

> /application/DB/presto/presto-server-.936